# How to use filepath in extractIssueData?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using request NPM package and request take two parameters
request (URL, callback);

Here I somehow want to pass extra argument to my callback function how do I do it.
This is the code I am trying to write

```
 function extractIssues(url,filepath){
    
    request(url,issueCb);
}

function issueCb(err,response,html)
{
  if(err){
      console.log(err+"at line 61");
  }
  else{
     extractIssueData(html);
  }
     
}
function extractIssueData(html){
  let selTool = cheerio.load(html);
  let arr = [];
  let issueLinksArr = selTool(".flex-auto.min-width-0.p-2.pr-3.pr-md-2 > a");
  
  let result="";
  for(let i = 0;i<issueLinksArr.length;i++){
     let issueLink = selTool(issueLinksArr[i]).attr("href");
     let content = selTool(issueLinksArr[i]).text().trim().split("/n")[0];
    
     let obj = {
        link :issueLink,
        content:content
     }
     
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    result = result + str + " ,"+ "\n" ; 

  }
       
  console.log(result);
   
}
```

I want to use filepath in extractIssueData so I need to first catch it in issueCb how do I do it
I can't find proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue disappears entirely if you simplify to use a single function! The following should be equivalent to, if not an improvement on, your code:

```
let extractIssues = async (url, filepath) => {
  
  // Wait for the html content of a `request` call
  let html = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // If an Error occurs reject with the error, otherwise resolve with
    // html data
    request(url, (err, res, html) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(html));
  });
  
  let selTool = cheerio.load(html);
  
  // Collect href and text content values from <a> elements
  let resultsArr = selTool(".flex-auto.min-width-0.p-2.pr-3.pr-md-2 > a")
    .map(issueLink => ({
      link: selTool(issueLink).attr("href"),
      content: selTool(issueLink).text().trim().split("/n")[0]
    }));
  
  // Print the array of link+content data
  console.log(resultsArr);
  
};
```

Note that within this function you have access to `filepath`, so you can use it as is necessary.

A solution without `async` looks like:

```
let extractIssues = (url, filepath) => {
  
  request(url, (err, res, html) => {
    
    if (err) throw err;
    
    let selTool = cheerio.load(html);
    
    // Collect href and text content values from <a> elements
    let resultsArr = selTool(".flex-auto.min-width-0.p-2.pr-3.pr-md-2 > a")
      .map(issueLink => ({
        link: selTool(issueLink).attr("href"),
        content: selTool(issueLink).text().trim().split("/n")[0]
      }));
    
    // Print the array of link+content data
    console.log(resultsArr);
  
  });
  
};
```

Once again this creates a scenario where `filepath` is available to be used as necessary within the function.

Note: If you are being "given instruction" not to use `async` *you are being done a disservice; `async` is a core feature and major selling point of javascript*. Once you become comfortable with `async` you will quickly regret ever having worked without it. I recommend you take the time to understand it! :)

Comment: thanku very much for your response but  i currently do not have command over async and was given instruction to not use those .

Comment: thanku thanku very much now i understand there was no need of creating extract issue function sperately just create the logic inside the callback of request.
Really appreciate your sincere efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I can create you an easy sample to use callback functions.
It's a stupid example I know but it helps you to understand how callbacks are working.

```
function myFunc(callback) {
  let errMessage = "This is error callback";
  let message = "This is normal message";
  callback(errMessage, message);
}

function myCallbackFunc(err, result) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log(result);
    return;
  }
  console.log(err);
}

myFunc(myCallbackFunc);
```

You won't use it like this but If you want to send a error callback, you should null to response param. Like this:

```
function myFunc(callback) {
  let errMessage = "This is error callback";
  let message = "This is normal message";
  let somethingBadHappened = true;
  
  if(somethingBadHappened) {
    return callback(errMessage, null);
  }
  callback(null, message)
}

function myCallbackFunc(err, result) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log(result);
    return;
  }
  console.log(err);
}

myFunc(myCallbackFunc);
```

Comment: Thanku very much for the reply but i am still trying to get your solution

Comment: You can test that function in this [playground](https://replit.com/languages/nodejs) and check it out there.